# 4k mode hard disk partition

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, fdisk

I am trying to create a 256 MB primary partition for my 320 Gig hdd using `fdisk`.

Since, the drive support 4k I wanted to try the emulation mode.
so, for 256 Mb of 512 K blocks leads me with below block counts.

```
fdisk -u /dev/sdb n p 1 4096 528384 w
```

In **Gparted UI** it is showing `256 MB` but with `parted -l` below is the output:

```
Model: ATA HGST HTE545032A7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      2097kB  271MB  268MB  primary  ext3         boot
```

Why is this different?

Comment: I agree w/ Mark. This is likely due to the use of 1M bytes (1,000,000) vs. 2^20 bytes = 1MB. Seagate even describes it on their website: http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/172191en